# How to create a maven folder structure for .ftl files

Tags: maven, ant

I am converting my ant build project into Maven but stuck at a point to where should i keep the .ftl file .

Comment: please be more specific and give examples of what you're having an issue with.

Comment: Depends on how the files are used in your build / application. Are they consumed by some maven build plugin? Than it's usually something like `src/main/[language]/` e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925057/how-do-i-use-a-template-code-generator-eg-freemarker-in-maven - on the other hand if you use them at runtime, you probably want to put them in `src/main/resources` https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html